# openstack installation repository in ubuntu focal

Tags: openstack, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install cloud-archive yoga for ubuntu 20.04 focal.

```
 add-apt-repository cloud-archive:yoga

 Ubuntu Cloud Archive for OpenStack Yoga
 More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
ubuntu-cloud-keyring is already the newest version (2020.02.11.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Err:2 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal-updates/yoga InRelease                                              
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Hit:3 https://it1.mirror.vhosting-it.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                  
Hit:4 https://it1.mirror.vhosting-it.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://it1.mirror.vhosting-it.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://it1.mirror.vhosting-it.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/yoga/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The problem is that connection failed. I do

```
dig http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31378
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com. 44 IN A 185.125.189.10

;; Query time: 1163 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Apr 30 06:12:33 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86
```

ip 185.125.189.10 resolved is different from Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80].
How can I solve it?

Comment: The archive works for me, maybe there was just a temporary interruption of services, just try again.

Comment: I read that the Keystone repository is already available in Ubuntu 20.04 without the need to add it. However, when I tried to install Keystone, it did not seem to be a service. How can I install Keystone as a keystone.service? Can you provide me with some information about the Keystone installation?

Comment: Keystone hasn’t been a „classic service“ for years. It’s a wsgi process run by apache. I recommend to follow the installation docs: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/install/index-ubuntu.html